# Asp.net Web referencing .net standard 2.0 library throws runtime exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.6.1

I'm having trouble with a project that contains an asp.net site (target .net 4.6.1) that references a .net standard 2.0 class library that uses entity framework core to do some database stuff. My solution compiles fine but when it executes the entity framework core code an exception gets thrown: "Could not load file or assembly System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0".

Anyone has any ideas on how i can proceed to troubleshoot this? I have tried various ideas but no luck..

Comment: [Referencing .NET Standard Assemblies from both .NET Core and .NET Framework](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReferencingNETStandardAssembliesFromBothNETCoreAndNETFramework.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try cleaning your project as well as bin and obj folder. Then restore and rebuild your solution by issuing

```
dotnet restore
dotnet rebuild
```

and test your solution.

If this does not work I suggest you to explicitly include `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` nuget package into your main .Net Framework v4.6.1 and try again

Answer (score 0):

It worked when i set the target framework for the web application to 4.7.2 and added entity framework core via nuget to the web application.